I Can't Create Custom Runtime Builder With Jlink
I am unable to create a custom image using jlink because the MySQL JDBC Connector is not modular. Despite ensuring that the mysql-connector-j dependency is present in the dependency folder within the target directory, I still encounter the error:
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/antriannew
I have verified the following:

The mysql-connector-j is included in the pom.xml as a dependency.
The mysql-connector-j jar file is present in the dependency folder after the build.
My project works correctly when run through IntelliJ IDEA but fails when built and run using jlink.

I also ensured that:
I used the maven-assembly-plugin to package the application with all dependencies.
The javafx-maven-plugin is configured correctly to include com.mysql.cj.jdbc as an automatic module.
The issue persists, indicating that the MySQL JDBC driver is not being recognized as a module during runtime when using the custom image created by jlink.
Github
Please help me and provide me with step by step what should I do

Jlink can’t link automatic modules,  you need to add those manually after creating the image or package using jpackage instead.
